# Order by two columns in opposite direction in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by

I have price table:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS price (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT,
    shop INTEGER NOT NULL,
    product INTEGER NOT NULL,
    delivery VARCHAR(100),
    score REAL,
    opinions INTEGER,
    avaiable INTEGER,
    price REAL,
    time INTEGER NOT NULL,
    FOREIGN KEY(shop) REFERENCES shop(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(product) REFERENCES product(id),
    FOREIGN KEY(time) REFERENCES time(id)
);
```

I need to display the prices but order should be score from bigger to smallest, opinions from bigger to smallest but price should be the opposite from smallest to biggest.

This don't work:

```
select score, opinions, shop.name, price from price
left join shop on shop.id = price.shop
order by score asc, price desc;
```

Is it possible in SQLite?

My data look like this:

```
4.5 |  3380 | abfoto.pl         | 9199.0
5.0 |  1304 | cyfrowe.pl        | 9299.0
5.0 |   744 | fotoforma.pl      | 9399.0
5.0 |   199 | fotopanorama.pl   | 9099.0
4.0 |   911 | empik.com         | 9099.0
5.0 |  3847 | komputronik.pl    | 9190.0
5.0 |  1053 | sferis.pl         | 9199.0
5.0 |   578 | fotoplus.pl       | 9199.0
5.0 |    24 | e-oko.pl          | 9199.0
5.0 |    55 | foto-kolodziej.pl | 9299.0
5.0 |   164 | foto-szop.pl      | 9299.0
5.0 | 47139 | allegro.pl        | 9347.77
5.0 |   526 | fotosoft.pl       | 9399.0
4.5 |  7129 | mall.pl           | 9401.0
5.0 |   144 | fotostrada.pl     | 9499.0
```

on top there should be `5.0|fotopanorama.pl|9099.0`.

Comment: You seem to know the purpose of ASC and DESC. So if you want *score from bigger to smallest, opinions from bigger to smallest but price should be the opposite from smallest to biggest* why do you have in your code: `score asc, price desc`?

Answer (score 1):

> order should be score from bigger to smallest, opinions from bigger to smallest but price should be the opposite from smallest to biggest.

I think you want:

```
order by score + 0 desc, opininon desc, price
```

Note that since `score` is stored as string, it is safer to turn it to a number before sorting (hence the `+ 0`).

Comment: What's he purpose of the `+ 0`?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: that's because this column is defined as string in the table...

Comment: Can you really add a number to a string in SQLite? Sounds scary

Comment: score as string, It was mistake the old db had it as "5 / 5" that's why it was string. It should be the a number. You can remove this from the answer, I will update the question.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name: as I see it, that's a number stored as string. `+ 0` does implicit conversion to a number.